# Laravel Project ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, mysql, server, laravel-5, centos7

I am facing a very critical issue on server where i hosted a Laravel application project.I have some other projects hosted there. Some times I see "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"  error on browser. But at the same time other Project working well.If i restart the service "httpd" of that project it starts working again. I tried to go every solution i got from internet.but no luck.[image]

Comment: May be execution time going out did you checked it ?

Comment: can you please help me how to check it ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please make a try adding this line at the top of .htaccess file in ur project

> php_flag opcache.enable Off

hope it works for you.

Comment: "opcache" is a huge speed improvement, and disabling it may **not** always be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Try add following code at the 1st line in .htaccess file

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

And increase memory in your php.ini

```
memory_limit = 1024M
```