# Laravel website ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error when using php7.3.16

Tags: php, laravel

When I use browser(chrome, firefox) to browse localhost laravel website (using php7.3.16), It shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error. 
It happens in different laravel projects with different laravel versions(5.8, 6.2, 7.0)
PHP Version 7.3.16
macOS Catalina 10.15.4
php is installed using macport

run "composer install": ok

run "php artisan view:clear; php artisan config:clear; php artisan cache:clear": ok

phpinfo() in browser: ok

load laravel website in browser: fail
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

when I use php7.2 instead of php7.3, problem solved
But I want to use php7.3

```
$port installed | grep php73
  php73 @7.3.16_0+libedit (active)
  php73-apache2handler @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-curl @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-gd @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-gettext @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-iconv @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-intl @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-mbstring @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-mcrypt @1.0.3_0 (active)
  php73-mysql @7.3.16_0+mysqlnd (active)
  php73-openssl @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-redis @5.2.1_0 (active)
  php73-xsl @7.3.16_0 (active)
  php73-zip @1.18.2_0 (active)
$ port installed | grep php72
  php72 @7.2.29_0+libedit (active)
  php72-apache2handler @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-curl @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-gd @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-gettext @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-iconv @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-intl @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-mbstring @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-mcrypt @1.0.3_0 (active)
  php72-mysql @7.2.29_0+mysqlnd (active)
  php72-openssl @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-redis @5.2.1_0 (active)
  php72-xsl @7.2.29_0 (active)
  php72-zip @1.18.2_0 (active)
```

Comment: You say you have this problem with multiple projects. Do you have the problem with ALL projects running on your 'localhost'?

Comment: Have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248306/laravel-project-err-empty-response ?

Comment: All laravel projects have this problem, one native php project is able to show phpinfo()

Comment: I tried adding this line at the top of .htaccess file in my projects, but it doesn't work
php_flag opcache.enable Off

Comment: Could you share some more info about your situation? Like what webserver are you using? is that the macport thing?  Do yu use https or http? What have you already tried? Have you checked the php 7.2>>7.3 upgrade notes(https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.php)?

Comment: Thanks. As I remember, I use 7.3.15 before and it works for a long time.
Recently, I reinstall the php, it upgrades to 7.3.16 and the problem occurs.
I use https. web server: apache2 @2.4.41_2+preforkmpm (active)

Comment: Have you checked the php.ini, maybe you enabled some settings/modules in the old installation which yuo forgot in the new installation?

Comment: I compared php.ini between 7.2 and 7.3, only commented lines have different

Comment: I mean compare the previous 7.3 installation vs current 7.3 ;)