# Revert of Filepond is not working on Live server but works on local Server while using laravel

Tags: laravel, delete-file, revert, filepond

```
It was all good and working when i was testing my code on local server. 
But always when i test the same code on live server it gives errors.
Actually, I am working with Filepond using Laravel and creating a website.
```

This is Edit Blade Js

```
<pre>    
<script>
    // Register the plugin with FilePond
    FilePond.registerPlugin(
        FilePondPluginMediaPreview,
        FilePondPluginImagePreview,
        FilePondPluginFileValidateType,
        FilePondPluginFileValidateSize,
        FilePondPluginFilePoster
    );

    const inputElement1 = document.querySelector('input[id="card_image_id"]');
    const inputElement2 = document.querySelector('input[id="video"]');
    const workimages = document.querySelector('input[id="workimages"]');

    const pond1 = FilePond.create(inputElement1, {
        acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],
        fileValidateTypeDetectType: true,

        maxFileSize: 10000000, //10 mbs max size
        allowFileSizeValidation: true,

        onaddfilestart: (file) => {
            isLoadingCheck();
        },
        onprocessfile: (files) => {
            isLoadingCheck();
        },
    });

    const pond2 = FilePond.create(inputElement2, {
        acceptedFileTypes: ['video/*'],
        fileValidateTypeDetectType: true,

        maxFileSize: 35000000, //35 mbs max size
        allowFileSizeValidation: true,

        onaddfilestart: (file) => {
            isLoadingCheck();
        },
        onprocessfile: (files) => {
            isLoadingCheck();
        },
    });

    const pond3 = FilePond.create(workimages, {
        acceptedFileTypes: ['image/*'],
        fileValidateTypeDetectType: true,

        maxFileSize: 10000000, //10 mbs max size
        allowFileSizeValidation: true,

        onaddfilestart: (file) => {
            isLoadingCheck();
        },
        onprocessfile: (files) => {
            isLoadingCheck();
        },
    });

    FilePond.setOptions({
        server: {
            process: '/tempupload',
            revert: '/tempdelete/{{ $fileid }}',
            // fetch: '/tempfetch',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                'work_id': '{{ $work->id }}'
            },
        },
    });
    
</script>
</pre>
```

This is web routes

```
<pre>
    Route::delete('tempdelete', [WorkController::class, 'tempdelete'])->name('tempdelete');
</pre>
```

This is controller

```
<pre>
    public function tempdelete()
    {
        $this->WorkService->tempdelete();
        return response()->json(null, 204);
    }
</pre>
```

This is Service

```
<pre>
  public function tempdelete()
    {
        $work_id = (request()->header('work-id')); 
        $temporaryfile = TemporaryFile::where('fid', request()->getContent())->first();
        if ($temporaryfile) {
            $filesexist_in_workimages =  Workimage::where([
                'size' => $temporaryfile->size,
                'name' => $temporaryfile->filename,
                'work_id' => $work_id,
            ])->first();
            if (isset($filesexist_in_workimages)) {
                if (File::exists($filesexist_in_workimages->folder)) {
                    File::delete($filesexist_in_workimages->folder);
                }
                $filesexist_in_workimages->delete();
            }

            if (isset($temporaryfile->folder)) {
                if (File::exists($temporaryfile->folder . $temporaryfile->filename)) {
                    File::delete($temporaryfile->folder . $temporaryfile->filename);
                }
            }
            $temporaryfile->delete();
        }
    }
</pre>
```

The point is that this code works perfectly for deleting a file on local server but shows this error on live server
On Console:

```
<pre> 
DELETE http://brokenclient1.000webhostapp.com/tempdelete net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
</pre>
```

On Network:
Failed to load responce, No data found for source with given identifier
When i try to dd on controller or service it does not even works to show dd.

Comment: Can you give a try to Incognito Mode? Or use diff browser. Maybe it's cache issue

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not connected with FilePond. Are you using Postman or Insomnia to check your API and connection? Check your server settings. Try this solution provided in this link

[Laravel Project ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248306/laravel-project-err-empty-response)

This is typical server error response or sometimes Internet Service Provider error.