# Laravel Fortify endpoints returning ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: php, laravel, ionic-framework, cors, fortify

Im trying to call my Laravel API from an Ionic application, but when i try it this error is showed on console "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Calls to api routes are workin, Fortify endpoints are the ones that are not working

The calls to Fortify endpoints, like register or login, do not returns a response, its just the error what i get, not a code response or anything.

I have already done calls from postman and it works correctly, but in browser is not working

I'd love and be so grateful if someone who knows more about this than me could help me

this is the call from Ionic app

```
register() {
    this.http
      .post('http://mydomain.host.com/register', {
        name: this.name,
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password,
        password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation,
      })
      .subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

this is also my laravel 'config/cors.php'

```
 'paths' => ['*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => [
        'http://localhost:8100'
        ],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => ['*'],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ['*'],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: Did you try? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42249470/5192105

Comment: yeah, idk what is happening to mi API, it's very weird